# Missing TabBar Review Icon when in Settings screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

When I am on settings screen, I see that the Review Icon (favorite) is missing. It shows when I am back on Review screen. Why is that happening. See the screenshot I took. Pasting relevant code snippet from my project for reference.

[image]

```
 const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      map: { screen: MapScreen },
      deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
      review: {
        screen: StackNavigator({
          review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
          settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
        })
      }
    }, {
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      tabBarOptions: {
        labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 }
      }
    });

class ReviewScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = props => {
    const {navigation} = props;
    const {navigate} = navigation;
    return {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
            return <Icon name="favorite" size={30} color={tintColor} />

        },
        headerTitle: 'Review Jobs',
        headerRight: (
            <Button
                title="Settings"
                onPress={() => navigate('settings')}
                backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                color="rgba(0, 122, 255, 1)"
            />
        )
    }
  }
```

Leads here is appreciated.

Comment: what is tintColor set to? try setting it hard coded to black

Comment: Did you try setting the icon on navigation create and not on screen?

Comment: But why is it working for Map and Jobs? Link to my gitlab repo https://gitlab.com/agrawall.lokesh/job-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with your code, since you're setting every icon's `tintColor` in the `static navigationOptions` as

```
tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
        return <Icon name="favorite" size={30} color={tintColor}/>

      }
```

and there is none for the `Settings Screen`, which also expects an `Icon` as it is inside the `TabNavigator`, therefore `null` is being rendered there.

Therefore you need to set the `navigationOptions` in the `Settings Screen` as

```
static navigationOptions = props => {
    const {navigation} = props;
    const {navigate} = navigation;
    return {
      tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
        return <Icon name="favorite" size={30} color={tintColor}/>

      }
    }
  }
```

or you may add the default icons in your `App.js` navigation file as

```
screen: TabNavigator({
        map: { screen: MapScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Icon name="favorite" size={30} color={tintColor}/>
                )
            }
        },
// ....so on
```

***Hope it helps!***